# How to migrate Laravel project password to Go project?

Tags: laravel, go, password-hash

There is a Laravel project, but has now been refactored into a Go project.

How can a user's password saved using Laravel be verified with Go?

[UPDATE]

I use `Hash::make($password)` store password in `Laravel`

Comment: It depends on how did you store the password. If you apply `bcrypt` function before storing the password, you can use Golang's [`bcrypt`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt) to encrypt the password then compare the result against the password stored in Laravel Project.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am using following codes solved the question

```
import "golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt"

func Hash(str string) (string, error) {
    hashed, err := bcrypt.GenerateFromPassword([]byte(str), bcrypt.DefaultCost)
    return string(hashed), err
}

func IsSame(str string, hashed string) bool {
    return bcrypt.CompareHashAndPassword([]byte(hashed), []byte(str)) == nil
}
```